# Regex to get sequence of number that can or cannot have sapeces between them

Tags: regex

I have the following regex: `[0-9]{2,3}[\s]?[.]?[\s]?[0-9]{3}[\s]?[.]?[\s]?[0-9]{3}[\s]?[\/-]?[\s]?[0-9]{2}`

It validates a pattern like `999.999.999-99`, also considering spaces (e.g., `999 999 999 99`, `999 .999. 999- 99`).

Let's take a little piece of this regex to simplify: `[0-9]{3, 2}`. How can I extend this regex to match something like `9 99`, `99 9`, `9 9 9`?

Comment: You are matching 3 chunks, these `9 99` and `99 9` are 2 chunks

Comment: *"Something like"*: that is quite vague. What are looking for? Should two spaces be allowed, can they occur anywhere? What about hyphens and dots? Same rules as for spaces?

Comment: If you want to match 11 digits, where spaces, dots and hyphens may occur anywhere, then `(?:\d[\s.-]*){11}`

Comment: Only one space should be allowed. For the rest, you should take in account the context of the full pattern explained. Dots and hyphens should only appear where I specified, but spaces could appear anywhere.

Comment: @trincot in your regex, how can I restrict to match only when one space appear? With that I mean: doesn't match if I have two spaces in sequence, but accept one space between each characters (although not mandatory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[0-9]{2,3}`, you could use `(?:\d\h?){2,3}`. This means that optionally every matched digit can be followed by a (horizontal) white space character (a space, a non-breaking space, a narrow space, ...).

The total regular expression could look like this:

[`(?:\d\h?){2,3}(?:\.\h?)?(?:\d\h?){3}(?:\.\h?)?(?:\d\h?){3}(?:[\/-]\h?)?\d\h?\d`](https://regex101.com/r/DvKVrz/1)

It will match the following strings:

- `999.999.999-99`
- `999 999 999 99`
- `999 .999. 999- 99`

But now also when single spaces occur within digit groups:

- `9 99. 99 9 .999 - 99`
- `9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9`
- `99 9 .999 . 999- 9 9`

But **not** when double spaces occur or dots or hyphens are misplaced:

- `9 9  9. 99 9 .999 - 99`
- `9 9 9 9-9 9 9 9 9 9 9`
- `99. 9 999 . 999- 9 9`

Answer (score 1):

## Forward

Your question:

> Let's take a little piece of this regex to simplify: [0-9]{3, 2}. How can I extend this regex to match something like 9 99, 99 9, 9 9 9

is an example of an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I recommend you provide the a full list of possible text you'd like to match along with examples of text you'd like not to match.

## Proposed solution

First off in your expression `[0-9]{3,2}` the `3,2` is not valid. Here you're saying the proceeding character class `[0-9]` must appear at least 3 times, and can appear at most 2 times. This logic prevents the match of even occurring because the match can not be at the same time 3 or more times and 2 or less.

This regex

`[0-9]\s[0-9]\s[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]\s[0-9]|[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Will do the following:

- Match numbers in the following formats:

  - `9 9 9`, `9 99`, `99 9`, and `999`

See also [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KLCkqT/1)

Please keep in mind there are plenty of obvious edge cases where this expression will give odd results for. Since the basis of your question was to modify `[0-9]{3,2}` then this is a reasonable approach.